# ARM Assembly - Change input file to only include capital letters and spaces, write to output

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm taking an x86 class right now, and we have an ARM assembly assignment, which is a copy of an x86 asssignment we did. Basically it reads in from a file, changes lowercase letters to uppercase, and keeps spaces. So it only writes capital letters (change the lowercase letters if they are lowercase), and copy the spaces, while getting rid of numbers and characters. We are using only hex characters 00h-7F (even though the lowest usable character we have is 0x20). I tried to convert my code from x86 to ARM but it just goes straight through, without writing to an output. Any Idea why, and how to fix it?

I wrote the sections labeled "check if lowercase" "check if uppercase" and "check if space"

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
; File:     ARMkey.s
;
; Function: This program copies an ASCII file
;           It assumes the file uses CR/LF as the end of line sequence
;           - It opens an input file named key.in
;           - It opens an output file named key.out
;           - It reads one line of text from the input file.
;           - It writes that one line to the output file, only using chars 00h-7Fh then a CR LF
;           - It loops until it reaches end of file
;           - It closes the input and output file
;
;
;---------------------------------------------------------------------


;----------------------------------
; Software Interrupt values
;----------------------------------
         .equ SWI_Open,  0x66     ;Open  a file
         .equ SWI_Close, 0x68     ;Close a file
         .equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69     ;Write a null-ending string
         .equ SWI_RdStr, 0x6a     ;Read a string and terminate with null char
         .equ SWI_Exit,  0x11     ;Stop execution
;----------------------------------

         .global   _start
         .text

_start:
;----------------------------------
; open input file
; - r0 points to the file name
; - r1 0 for input
; - the open swi is 66h
; - after the open r0 will have the file handle
;----------------------------------
         ldr  r0, =InFileName     ;r0 points to the file name
         ldr  r1, =0              ;r1 = 0 specifies the file is input
         swi  SWI_Open            ;open the file ... r0 will be the file handle
         ldr  r1, =InFileHandle   ;r1 points to handle location
         str  r0, [r1]            ;store the file handle
;----------------------------------


;----------------------------------
; open output file
; - r0 points to the file name
; - r1 1 for output
; - the open swi is 66h
; - after the open r0 will have the file handle
;----------------------------------
         ldr  r0, =OutFileName    ;r0 points to the file name
         ldr  r1, =1              ;r1 = 1 specifies the file is output
         swi  SWI_Open            ;open the file ... r0 will be the file handle
         ldr  r1, =OutFileHandle  ;r1 points to handle location
         str  r0, [r1]            ;store the file handle
;----------------------------------


;----------------------------------
; read a string from the input file
; - r0 contains the file handle
; - r1 points to the input string buffer
; - r2 contains the max number of characters to read
; - the read swi is 6ah
; - the input string will be terminated with 0
;----------------------------------
_read:                            ;
         ldr  r0, =InFileHandle   ;r0 points to the input file handle
         ldr  r0, [r0]            ;r0 has the input file handle
         ldr  r1, =String         ;r1 points to the input string
         ldr  r2, =128            ;r2 has the max size of the input string
         swi  SWI_RdStr           ;read a string from the input file
         cmp  r0,#0               ;no characters read means EOF
         beq  _exit               ;so close and exit
;----------------------------------

;----------------------------------
; Check if Lower Case Letter
;----------------------------------

     cmp    r1, #0x61              ;check against lowercase a
     blt    _notlower              ;if less go to notlow
     cmp    r1, #0x7A              ;check against lowercase z
     bgt    _notlower
     sub    r1, r1, #0x14          ;Make letter uppercase
     bal    _read

;----------------------------------
; Check if Upper Case Letter
;----------------------------------

_notlower:
     cmp    r1, #0x41             ;dl < A
     blt    _space                ;jump to not letter
     cmp    r1, #0x5A             ;dl > Z
     blt    _space                ;jump to not letter

;----------------------------------
; Check if Space
;----------------------------------

_space:
     cmp    r1, #0x20             ; r1 = space?
     beq    _read                 ; yes, get new letter


;----------------------------------
; Write the outputs string
;----------------------------------
_write:                           ;
         ldr  r0, =OutFileHandle  ;r0 points to the output file handle
         ldr  r0, [r0]            ;r0 has the output file handle
         ldr  r1, =String         ;r1 points to the output string
         swi  SWI_PrStr           ;write the null terminated string
                                  ;
         ldrb r1, [r1]            ;get the first byte of the line



         cmp  r1, #0x1A           ;if line was DOS eof then do not write CRLF
         beq  _read               ;so do next read
                                  ;
         ldr  r1, =CRLF           ;r1 points to the CRLF string
         swi  SWI_PrStr           ;write the null terminated string
                                  ;
         bal  _read               ;read the next line
;----------------------------------


;----------------------------------
; Close input and output files
; Terminate the program
;----------------------------------
_exit:                            ;
         ldr  r0, =InFileHandle   ;r0 points to the input  file handle
         ldr  r0, [r0]            ;r0 has the input file handle
         swi  SWI_Close           ;close the file
                                  ;
         ldr  r0, =OutFileHandle  ;r0 points to the output file handle
         ldr  r0, [r0]            ;r0 has the output file handle
         swi  SWI_Close           ;close the file
                                  ;
         swi  SWI_Exit            ;terminate the program
;----------------------------------


         .data
;----------------------------------
InFileHandle:  .skip 4            ;4 byte field to hold the input  file handle
OutFileHandle: .skip 4            ;4 byte field to hold the output file handle
                                  ;
InFileName:    .asciz "KEY.IN"   ;Input  file name, null terminated
                                  ;
String:        .skip 128          ;reserve a 128 byte string
                                  ;
CRLF:          .byte 13, 10, 0    ;CR LF
                                  ;
OutFileName:   .asciz "KEY.OUT"  ;Output file name, null terminated
;----------------------------------


         .end
```

The test file has the following chracters:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-/0123456789:;<=>?@
 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

And it should only output:

```
 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 
 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: You forgot to actually load the characters of the `String` read into `r1`. You will need a loop for that, since you read 128 bytes in one go. Of course you should use the number returned from the syscall, since you might have gotten less. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @Jester Could you explain how to do that? I'm taking this in a class, and our teacher hasn't provided us with much about ARM instructions at all, since it is an x86 assembly class.

Comment: You seem to have no problem accessing stuff in memory and you can do comparisons and branches, so what do you need explained?

Comment: It's the loading of the strings. My instructor has provided us with a joke of a section on notes for ARM assembly, so its been hard to figure out. We had an example program, which copies the entire file. I used that at my base and wrote the code that would change the output to what is specified in the original post. I know its pretty elementary, but I've had difficulty enough with how poorly my instructor is at providing help (or the lack of providing help is more like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple problems with your code, you should have probably made pseudocode or a flowchart first to figure out the algorithm.

Something like:

```c
while(ReadString(String, 128) != 0)
{
    for(r0 = r1 = String; *r0 != 0; r0++)
    {
        if (IsLower(*r0))
        {
            *r1++ = UpperCase(*r0);
        } else if (IsUpper(*r0) || IsSpace(*r0)) {
            *r1++ = *r0;
        }
    }
    *r0 = 0; /* terminate */
    WriteString(String);
}
```

Now, it's a simple matter to turn that into assembly code. Something like:

```
_read:
     ldr  r0, =InFileHandle   ;r0 points to the input file handle
     ldr  r0, [r0]            ;r0 has the input file handle
     ldr  r1, =String         ;r1 points to the input string
     ldr  r2, =128            ;r2 has the max size of the input string
     swi  SWI_RdStr           ;read a string from the input file
     cmp  r0,#0               ;no characters read means EOF
     beq  _exit               ;so close and exit

     ldr  r0, =String
     mov  r1, r0
charloop:
     ldrb r2, [r0]
     cmp  r2, #0
     beq  endofstring
     cmp  r2, #'z'
     bgt  skip
     cmp  r2, #'a'
     bge  lower
     cmp  r2, #'Z'
     bgt  skip
     cmp  r2, #'A'
     bge  copy
     cmp  r2, #' '
     beq  copy
     bal  skip
 lower:
     sub  r2, r2, #0x20
 copy:
     strb r2, [r1], #1
 skip:
     add  r0, r0, #1
     bal  charloop
 endofstring:
     strb r2, [r1]            ; copy the terminating zero

     ldr  r0, =OutFileHandle  ;r0 points to the output file handle
     ldr  r0, [r0]            ;r0 has the output file handle
     ldr  r1, =String         ;r1 points to the output string
     swi  SWI_PrStr           ;write the null terminated string
                              ;
     ldr  r1, =CRLF           ;r1 points to the CRLF string
     swi  SWI_PrStr           ;write the null terminated string
                              ;
     bal  _read               ;read the next line
```

Beware of bugs in the above code, I haven't tested it :)

PS: the difference from upper to lower is 0x20 not 20 which would be 0x14 as in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! I definitely see what you did vs what I had. Huge help in understanding my ARM assignment