# Check to see if a string is a palindrome without punctuation

Tags: assembly, arm

I have this code:

```
    AREA palindrome, CODE, READONLY

SWI_Exit EQU 0x11

      ENTRY

start

      LDR   r0,=string

      MOV   r1,r0

loop  LDRB  r2,[r1],#1

      CMP   r2,#0

      BNE   loop

      SUB   r1,r1,#2

      BL    pal

stop  SWI   SWI_Exit

 

pal   MOV   r10,#0x0

again LDRB  r3,[r0]

      LDRB  r4,[r1]

      CMP   r3,r4

      BNE   notpal

 

      CMP   r0,r1

      BEQ   waspal

      ADD   r2,r0,#1

      CMP   r2,r1

      BEQ   waspal

      ADD   r0,r0,#1

      SUB   r1,r1,#1

      B     again

 

waspal      MOV   r0,#0x1

notpal      MOV   r0, #0x2

 

string      DCB   "abcba",0

      END
```

But right now it only checks if it is a palindrome for strings that do not have any punctuation.  I would like it so that when I enter a string with or without punctuation and spaces it stores 1 in r0 and 2 if it is not.

So right now when I enter:

`"abcba"`

I get that it is a palindrome, but when I have

`"abc ba"`

It is counted as not a palindrome.

Also I have this bug where it does not store any value in register 0 when finishing the loop.  But if I change it so that I store the result in two different registers (one in r0 and one in r10) then it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can vastly simplify your loop-end condition.  `do{ ...; r0++, r1--; }while(r0<r1);`  You don't have to care about whether they pass each other or meet exactly, just `cmp` / `blo` (branch if unsigned "lower").

Then you can add skipping non-alphabetic characters to both pointer increments.  (You don't seem to even be trying to do that, so of course it finds that `"abc ba"` isn't a palindrome.  It's not when you consider all 6 bytes.)

Also, you're missing `bx lr` in your return paths.  Single-step with a debugger to see execution fall through both `mov r0, #value` instructions.

Comment: Do you mind if you can post an answer with the corrected code?  I'd really appreciate it.  I'm not really familiar with do while loops.

Comment: @StuartFong: I wasn't planning to do your homework for you.  There isn't even an attempt to skip punctuation.  I only posted this as an answer because it was getting too long for a comment.  Also, you haven't defined exactly what "punctuation" is.  Do you want to skip every non-alphabetic character, so you keep both lower and upper-case letters?  I assume only ASCII, not UTF-8 or something...  It should be as simple as replacing pointer-increment with scanning until you find the next alphabetic character in that direction (or hit the start or end of the string, so that's a corner case...)

Comment: Fair enough.  What I mean by punctuation is capitals, spaces, and any non alphabet character.  When you say it's as simple as "simple as replacing pointer-increment with scanning until you find the next alphabetic character in that direction" would there be a way to check the character is punctuation because I am using ASCII characters, and the range between them is 41-5A for capitals and 61-7A for lower case.  Is there an operation that just checks whether the character is in that range?

Comment: @StuartFong: yes, there are existing Stack Overflow Q&As about checking to see if a byte is an alphabetic character.  e.g. [How can I check if a character is a letter in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31824566) is an x86 version or an optimized range check (checks for upper or lower with a single sequence of OR / SUB / CMP+branch.)  Or a simplistic range-check that just does `c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'` the naive way, with two branches, in ARM asm: [ARM Assembly - Change input file to only include capital letters and spaces, write to output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31632020)